# Difference between か and のか

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-か

I am going through 'All About Particles', and came across the following two sentences:

> なぜ彼がそんなことをやったか、わかりません。
>
> どうして彼女がそんなつまらない本を読んでいるのか、不思議です。

What is the difference between using か in the first one and のか in the second? I have searched online, and のか seems to carry a sense of 'questioning the former'. Does that mean I could also use のか in the first sentence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the meaning is the same. 'questioning the former.'

> なぜ彼がそんなことをやったか、わかりません。
>
> なぜ彼がそんなことをやったのか、わかりません。
>
> どうして彼女がそんなつまらない本を読んでいるか、不思議です。
>
> どうして彼女がそんなつまらない本を読んでいるのか、不思議です。

are all natural.

## のか

This is a combination of の and か.
This の is called 準体言助詞, which makes a noun phrase out of a verb phrase.

「それを食べたのは、いけないことだ。」(It is bad that you ate it.)

Also, you can add か to a noun 「動物かは、分からない」(I am not sure if it is an animal.)

So, you can also add か to a noun phrase to make something similar.
「それを食べたのかは、分からない。」(I am not sure whether you ate it not.)

## か

か itself can follow a verb phrase to make a noun questioning phrase.
「それが食べられるかを知りたい。」(I want to know if I can eat it.)