# What is the difference between かと思った and のかと思った?

Tags: grammar

I understand that かと思った is used to mean something along the lines of "I thought", however I am unsure as to what difference there is when の is added in のかと思った. What is the function (question marker, nominalisation?) of the の particle in the first place, and how does it affect the nuance overall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between か and のか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33162)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between か and のか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33162/difference-between-%e3%81%8b-and-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the の in that position is an explanatory-の. Can you explain the difference between "見ました" and "見た**の**です"? Or the difference between "食べる?" and "食べる**の**?" If yes, the difference between かと思った and のかと思った is the same; in the latter, the verb before の is working as a clarification of the topic or situation at hand. In English, you seldom need to express this nuance explicitly, but the closest equivalent would be the phrase "it's that ～". In Japanese, you need の very often to make natural sentences.

- [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- [Question Markers: か and の](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/)

For example, let's compare 死ぬかと思った and 死ぬのかと思った. The former is a rather simple sentence meaning "I thought [I/you/he/she] almost died!", said after a narrow escape from death. On the other hand, the latter has an explanatory nuance around 死ぬ, so when translated verbosely, it's more like "I thought it meant [he/she] would die!". For example, you may say this when you noticed someone's [death flag](https://www.cbr.com/anime-death-hints-signs/) but that character didn't die.

I know this type of の is tricky to an English speaker, so please take your time to get accustomed to it. Also note that の has other usages.